# Adding a new node as a child is automatically adding the xmlns attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to modify an XML document. The XML is structured like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
 <Modelo39 xmlns="http://www.dgci.gov.pt/2002/OT" versao="1">
<Rosto>
<QuadroInicio />
<Quadro01>
  <Q01C01>555555555</Q01C01>
</Quadro01>
<Quadro06>
  <Rostoq06T>

  </Rostoq06T>
</Quadro06>
</Rosto>
</Modelo39>
```

I'm trying to add to **Rostoq06T** a new node like this:

```
<Rostoq06T-Linha numero="1">
<NIF>100000000</NIF>
<CodRend>01</CodRend>
<Rendimento>2500</Rendimento>
<Retido>500</Retido>
</Rostoq06T-Linha>
```

I'm creating a new element with the name **Rostoq06T-Linha** and i'm adding it properly to the node Rosto06T:

```
XmlElement node06T = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Rostoq06T-Linha");
node06T.SetAttribute("numero", linha.ToString());
//Here i add the elements to node06T
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Rostoq06T").Item(0).AppendChild(node06T);
```

My problem is that the Rosto06T-Linha is being generated like this:

```
<Rostoq06T-Linha numero="1" xmlns="">
```

I can't figure out why it's being added the attribute **xmlns** to this node, if this element is a child of **Rostoq06T**.

Can anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: Hi, I believe you should specify that you want an XmlNode as node type when calling xmlDoc.CreateElement, look at the overloads...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you created the `Rostoq06T-Linha` element **without** namespace, ie. with **empty namespace**.

You must use the proper `CreateElement` overload

```
XmlElement node06T = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Rostoq06T-Linha","http://www.dgci.gov.pt/2002/OT");
```

Unfortunately, you have to specify full namespace for all children you create!

Comment: This is a XML that has to be sent to Portuguese Finances Resources. Do you think that having the xmls attribute in Rostoq06T-Linha will affect the entire validation of XML?

Comment: `xmlns` is not an attribute, it is a namespace definition. Having an incorrect namespace on an element is comparable to having an incorrect local name on the element.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the namespace as i had in the <Modelo39> and now, when i save the xml Document i've only a namespace in <Modelo39>. All other empties xml namespaces had disappear. I guess it's because the compiler see that the namespace is already in a parent node, so he don't add another one with the same value.